# How to delete data from an entire related MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

```
tbl_car
id | name
1 | toyota

tbl_brand
id | brand_name | **car_id** (one to many)
1 | brand1 | 1
2 | brand2 | 1


tbl_item
id | item_name | **brand_id** (one to many)
1 | brand1_item1 | 1
2 | brand1_item2 | 1
3 | brand2_item1 | 2
4 | brand2_item2 | 2
```

I want to delete data id= 1 from tbl_car, I try

`DELETE tbl_car a LEFT JOIN tbl_brand b ON a.id = b.car_id LEFT JOIN tbl_item c ON b.id = c.brand_id WHERE a.id = 1`

but it didn't work. What I want is to delete tbl_car id = 1 and the entire data from relation table.

Comment: Look into ON DELETE CASCADE option for foreign keys

Comment: i use that, but i read so many article told that ON DELETE CASCADE is bad idea. like this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74627/difference-between-on-delete-cascade-on-update-cascade-in-mysql

Comment: @plonknimbuzz The reason not to use cascading is the same as not to use a multiple table deleting in one statement.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

Comment: @PaulSpiegel so, can you tell me the right way to do this? i always use ignore foreign key before. but now i want try the right way

Comment: [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) is your friend. Look at the first example.

Comment: thank you very much, bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can try like this:**

```
DELETE a.*,b.*,c.* FROM tbl_car a LEFT JOIN tbl_brand b ON a.id = b.car_id LEFT JOIN tbl_item c ON b.id = c.brand_id WHERE a.id = 1
```

**or try using a trigger after delete in the table tbl_car**

```
  delimiter $$
    CREATE TRIGGER `after_delete_Car`     
      AFTER DELETE ON `tbl_car`     
      FOR EACH ROW     
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM tbl_brand WHERE car_id=OLD.id;
      DELETE FROM tbl_item WHERE brand_id=OLD.id;
    END
    $$
    delimiter ;
```

Comment: trigger is the right thing to do this. but i prefer on delete cascade. thank you danilo for your time and answer